# Call FA2 transfer from another smart-contract with archertype

Tags: fa2

I’m trying to call a FA2 transfer function from another smart-contract but I’m not sure how to write it in archetype. Here is my code so far

```
archetype Test(
    a_contractToken : address, a_quantity: nat, a_debtor: address, a_creditor: address,
)

record transfer_destination {
  to_dest           : address;
  token_id_dest     : nat;
  token_amount_dest : nat
} as ((%to_, (token_id, amount)))

record transfer_param {
  tp_from : address;
  tp_txs  : list<transfer_destination>;
} as ((%from_, %txs))


entry exchange()  {
      const transaction = {
        from_ = a_debtor;
        txs = [{
            to_ = a_creditor;
            token_id = 0;
            amount = a_quantity
    }]
    };
  transfer 0tz to a_contractToken call %transfer<list<transfer_param>>((transaction))
}
```

But this doesn’t compile. Thank you for you help !

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Tezos stackexchange. You've mentioned that your code doesn't compile. Please include any compiler error messages or warnings that might help someone debug this

Answer (score 1):

I just typed `const transaction` as a `transfer_param` type and used the name of the field you defined. Also, `%transfer` takes a list of `transfer_param` as input, so `[transaction]` instead of just `transaction`:

```
archetype Test(
    a_contractToken : address, a_quantity: nat, a_debtor: address, a_creditor: address,
)

record transfer_destination {
  to_dest           : address;
  token_id_dest     : nat;
  token_amount_dest : nat
} as ((%to_, (token_id, amount)))

record transfer_param {
  tp_from : address;
  tp_txs  : list<transfer_destination>;
} as ((%from_, %txs))


entry exchange()  {
      const transaction : transfer_param = {
        tp_from = a_debtor;
        tp_txs = [{
            to_dest = a_creditor;
            token_id_dest = 0;
            token_amount_dest = a_quantity
    }]
    };
  transfer 0tz to a_contractToken call %transfer<list<transfer_param>>([transaction])
}
```